# Databricks: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I know there are several other questions about this error message, but none seems to relate to the problem I am currently facing. I am streaming from a JSON file (this part works):

```
gamingEventDF = (spark
.readStream
.schema(eventSchema) 
.option('streamName','mobilestreaming_demo') 
.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
.json(inputPath) 
)
```

Next I want to use writeStream to append it to a table:

```
def writeToBronze(sourceDataframe, bronzePath, streamName):
(sourceDataframe.rdd
.spark
.writeStream.format("delta")
.option("checkpointLocation", bronzePath + "/_checkpoint")
.queryName(streamName)
.outputMode("append") 
.start(bronzePath)
)
```

When I now run:

```
writeToBronze(gamingEventDF, outputPathBronze, "bronze_stream")
```

I am getting the error: AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with `writeStream.start()`

Btw: when I delete the .rdd, I am getting another error ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'spark')

Any idea what I got wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

writeStream method is available on dataframe class not on SparkSession.

Below code should work for you.

```
def writeToBronze(sourceDataframe, bronzePath, streamName):
  (sourceDataframe
  .writeStream.format("delta")
  .option("checkpointLocation", bronzePath + "/_checkpoint")
  .queryName(streamName)
  .outputMode("append") 
  .start(bronzePath)
  .awaitTermination())
```